# How to make a Spacer in Echo3 Client-side

Tags: echo3

I've just started playing with [echo3](http://demo.nextapp.com/echo3csjs/) and I'm using the client-side javascript libraries to create a GUI.

I would now like to make a status bar with some elements to the left, some on the right, and space in the middle. The bar itself occupies 100% of the page.

I don't know how large the objects on the left will be (they're text). On the right it will be 3 icons.

My question now is, how do I create a spacer between left and right items.

Layout is about:

```
|     text      |     text     |   (filler)     | icon    | icon    |
|(unknown size) |(unknown size)| (unknown size) | w=128px | w=128px |
```

I did see that the WindowPane has that sort of behaviour concerning the minimize and close buttons, but how that's done is not all that clear to me. I don't usually use JavaScript so that's also a bit of a learning experience.

All help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've no real solution for you, since I always used a framework that wrapped around echo3. But if I ran into problems like this I always tried to figure out how I'd do a layout in HTML and worked from there. In the end, everything in echo3 is obviously translated to HTML, so there has to be a solution in HTML.
Maybe it helps to mix percent and pixel widths. Try setting the width of the spacer to 100%.